# Angular : Only void and foreign elements can be self closed "datalist"

Tags: angular, typescript

I'm trying to make a dropdown list from an existing array `labelType` with the user still able to write a "custom" labelType.

However, I'm getting an error on my console :

```
Only void and foreign elements can be self closed "datalist" ("ass="form-control" id="groupLabel" required [(ngModel)]="label.groupLabel" name="groupLabel">
  [ERROR ->]<datalist id="labelTypes"/>
    <option value>select a label type</option>
    <o"): ng:///AppModule/LabelsFormsComponent.html@21:6
```

here's my html :

```js
let labelType = ['parking', 'title', 'country'];
```

```html
<form #myForm="ngForm">
  <div class="labelFormDiv">
    <div class="form-group">
          <label for="groupLabel">label group</label>
          <input type="text" list="labelTypes" class="form-control" id="groupLabel" required [(ngModel)]="label.groupLabel" name="groupLabel">
          <datalist id="labelTypes"/>
           <option value>select a label type</option>
           <option *ngFor="let labelTypes of labelType">{{labelTypes}}</option>
    </div>
 </div>
</form>

<button type="submit" [disabled]="!myForm.valid" class="btn btn-primary" (click)="submitLabelForm()">Sauver</button>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" (click)="cancelLabelForm()">Annuler</button>
```

Can someone please help me fix this issue ?

thank you

Answer (score 1):

`datalist` is not self-closing tag. You have to close it with `</datalist>` tag. It should look like this:

```html
<datalist id="labelTypes">
    <option value>select a label type</option>
    <option *ngFor="let labelTypes of labelType">{{labelTypes}}</option>
</datalist>
```

More on [docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/datalist)

Answer (score 1):

```html
   <datalist id="labelTypes">
        <option value>select a label type</option>
        <option *ngFor="let labelTypes of labelType">{{labelTypes}}</option>
      </datalist>
```

Answer (score 0):

Answer is quite easy and I kinda feel bad for this.

The `datalist` marker can't be self-closed : it needs a closing element at the end : `</datalist>`

Correct code :

```
<div class="form-group">
      <label for="groupLabel">label group</label>
      <input type="text" list="labelTypes" class="form-control" id="groupLabel" required [(ngModel)]="label.groupLabel" name="groupLabel">
      <datalist id="labelTypes">
         <option value>select a label type</option>
         <option *ngFor="let labelTypes of labelType">{{labelTypes}}</option>
      </datalist>
</div>
```